# Get printer details based on their status

Tags: visual-c++

Using  Windows Management Instrumentation (**WMI**) in  `VC++`  we  can  find the  SystemInfo  like  System Name  and  other  properties.

Example  for  **GetComputerName**  :

```
BOOL WINAPI GetComputerName(
  _Out_   LPTSTR  lpBuffer,
  _Inout_ LPDWORD lpnSize
);
```

There are  3 printers  attached  in  my  system 1  thermal  and  2 Shared  printers  ,

How can  i get  the  information about  printer  which  is  offline ?
How  can  i classify/list  printers  based  on  their  status  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See also [EnumPrinters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
DWORD flags = PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL | PRINTER_ENUM_CONNECTIONS;
DWORD bufsize, printerCount;
DWORD level = 2; //2 is for PRINTER_INFO_2

::EnumPrinters(flags, NULL, level, NULL, 0, &bufsize, &printerCount);
if (bufsize)
{
    BYTE* buffer = new BYTE[bufsize];
    ::EnumPrinters(flags, NULL, level, buffer, bufsize, &bufsize, &printerCount);

    if (bufsize && printerCount)
    {
        const PRINTER_INFO_2* info = (PRINTER_INFO_2*)buffer;
        for (DWORD i = 0; i < printerCount; i++)
        {
            if (info->pServerName)  cout << "pServerName: " << info->pServerName << endl;
            if (info->pPrinterName) cout << "pPrinterName: " << info->pPrinterName << endl;
            if (info->pShareName) cout << "pShareName: " << info->pShareName << endl;
            if (info->pPortName) cout << "pPortName: " << info->pPortName << endl;
            if (info->Attributes & PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_LOCAL) cout << "[local]\n";
            if (info->Attributes & PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_NETWORK) cout << "[network]\n";

            wcout << "status: " << info->Status << endl;
            if (info->Status & PRINTER_STATUS_ERROR) cout << "status: error\n";

            wcout << endl;
            info++;
        }
    }
    delete[] buffer;
}
```